# RunJobFlow operation: An instance group must have at least one instance

Tags: airflow, airflow-2.x, mwaa

I am writing code to run a psyaprk job using AIrflow 2.0.2,and I only need to start the master nodes, no core nodes

My JOB_FLOW_OVERRIDES is throwing an error saying: An instance group must have at least one instance. I already have InstanceCount= 1, still throwing me an error. Can someone help me

```
JOB_FLOW_OVERRIDES = {
    "Name": "Pitchbook ETL",
    "LogUri": "s3://aws-logs-5-us-west-1/elasticmapreduce/",
    "ReleaseLabel": "emr-6.2.0",
    "Applications": [
        {
            "Name": "Spark"
        },
    ],

    
    "Instances": {
      
        "InstanceGroups": [
            {
                "Name": "Master nodes",
                "Market": "ON_DEMAND",
                "InstanceRole": "MASTER",
                "InstanceType": "m5.xlarge",
                "InstanceCount": 1,
            },
            {"Name": "Core nodes", 
            "Market": "ON_DEMAND",
            "InstanceRole": "CORE",
            "InstanceType": "m5.xlarge", 
            "InstanceCount": 0,}
        ],
        "KeepJobFlowAliveWhenNoSteps": False,
        "TerminationProtected": False,

    },

    "BootstrapActions": [
        {
            "Name": "Install Dependencies",
            "ScriptBootstrapAction": {
                "Path": "s3://"+path+"-pyspark/pitchbook/install_python_modules.sh",
            }
        }

    ],
    "Configurations": [{"Classification":"core-site", 
                        "Properties":{"io.compression.codec.lzo.class":"", 
                                      "io.compression.codecs":"org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.GzipCodec,org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.DefaultCodec,\
                                      org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.BZip2Codec,org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.SnappyCodec"}}
                                   #       {"Classification":"export","Properties":{"TZ":"US/Central"}} 
                     ],

    "VisibleToAllUsers": True,
    "EbsRootVolumeSize" :20,
    "JobFlowRole": "EMR_EC2_DefaultRole",
    "ServiceRole": "EMR_DefaultRole",
    "Tags": [
        {
            "Key": "Environment",
            "Value": "Development"
        },
        {
            "Key": "Name",
            "Value": "Airflow EMR Project"
        },
        {
            "Key": "Owner",
            "Value": "Data Science Team"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Not sure, but  maybe this error is coming because of the second element of InstanceGroups where   InstanceCount is 0.  {"Name": "Core nodes", 
            "Market": "ON_DEMAND",
            "InstanceRole": "CORE",
            "InstanceType": "m5.xlarge", 
            "InstanceCount": 0,}  . This error is not related to airflow rather look like related to AWS API.  here we have simple example that I ran daily as integration test. https://github.com/astronomer/astronomer-providers/blob/main/astronomer/providers/amazon/aws/example_dags/example_emr_sensor.py#L72

Comment: worked after removing core nodes